# Are there any good example css files to look at as a basis?

Tags: css

I want to do some exercises for web front page designing.
Is there any good CSS file have been existed which can be used as base.css, that encapsulates atomic selectors.

Comment: I have placed the YUI reset.css in the base.css.

Comment: What are you asking for?

Comment: As [Bootstrap from Twitter](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), I just want a basis css for my experience app, and the css had better cover most of the html elements and easily replaceable in the future.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few out there, some of the biggest ones that come to mind are the [normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) reset/base sheet, [YUI base sheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/base/) and the most recent one, [Twitter's Bootstrap CSS sheet](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

By the way, you can always pick apart a base stylesheet from any HTML framework such as [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) or [960gs](http://960.gs/) and adapt it on your own project quite easily. It sounds a bit asinine to start one anew, due to the many selectors to pick at, and then the testing..tough :P ..but, as always, it's always good to go over these sheets to learn from them and see how the many HTML selectors stack up.

Comment: For a newbie, [Twitter's Bootstrap CSS sheet(http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) may be easier to use than _HTML5 Boilerplate_ and _960gs_, and has a better looks and feels. Isn't it?

Comment: That totally depends on how you look at it. To me, it is more jampacked with everything you might need all neatly stacked up, tested, cleaned and ready to go, straight from a reliable company with a team of experienced developers. So in a way, yeah. As always, make sure to experiment with other base sheets to see what shoe fits best.